# Recurrence relation and orthogonal monic polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

Let $\{p_n(x)\}_{n=0,1,..}$ be a set of monic orthogonal polynomial of order $n$ with respect to some weight function.

I have established through a series of excercises that they satistfy the recurrence relation
\begin{align}
 p_n(x) = (x+B_n)p_{n-1}(x) -C_n p_{n-2}(x)
\end{align}
Now, I must show that the set of integrals
\begin{equation}
\{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{p_n(x')}{x-x'}w(x')dx'\}_{n=0,1,..}
\end{equation}
satisfies the same recurrence relation. I have absolutely no idea of how to go about it.

**EDIT**: I manged to partially prove it, but I still need some input..

Define
\begin{align}
   \{f_n(x)\}_{n=0,1,...} := \left\{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{p_n(x')}{x-x'}w_2(x')d x' \right\}.
\end{align}
From the recurrence relation for $p_n$, we know
\begin{align}
 f_n(x)&=\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(x'+B_n)p_{n-1}(x')-C_np_{n-2}(x')}{x-x'}w_2(x')d x'\notag\\
                 &=\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x'p_{n-1}(x')}{x-x'}w_2(x')d x'+B_nf_{n-1}(x)-C_nf_{n-2}(x)
\end{align}

Thus I will have proved the relation if  I can show that 
\begin{align}
 xf_{n-1}(x)=\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x'p_{n-1}(x')}{x-x'}w_2(x')d x'
\end{align}

Comment: I tried to express $xp_{n-1}$ as a series of power of $x'$ or as a combination of polyomials of lower orders, but I can't seem to find a change of variable that 'brings out the x'

Comment: Related to but not exactly alike http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368292/why-must-orthogonal-polynomials-each-have-distinct-roots?rq=1, as the monic property is a given for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. For further reference:

\begin{align}
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x'p_{n-1}(x')}{x-x'}w_2(x')d x' &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\frac{x'p_{n-1}(x')}{x-x'}-\frac{xp_{n-1}(x')}{x-x'}\right]w_2(x')d x' +xf_{n-1}(x)\notag\\
 &= -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_{n-1}(x')w_2(x')d x' +xf_{n-1}(x)\notag\\
 &= -(p_{n-1},p_0)_2 +xf_{n-1}(x) \notag\\
 &= xf_{n-1}(x)
\end{align}

Explanation: We first add 0, then we use the fact that $p_n$ is monic and thus that $p_0=1$ to transform the integral into a inner product. With $n-1\neq 0$, this product equals zero and the sought identity follows. For $n=-1$ it breaks downs but so does the recurrence relation (it is defined for $n\geq1$).