Proof that monic polynomials $\{p_i(x)\}_{i = 0}^\infty$ each have $i$ distinct real roots in $[a, b]$
Problem:  Let $\{p_i(x)\}_{i = 0}^\infty$ be orthogonal polynomials in the interval $[a, b]$ with respect to the inner product $(p(x), q(x)) \equiv \int_a^b p(x)q(x) \ dx$, where $p_i(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $i$. Show that $p_i(x)$ has $i$ distinct real roots in $[a, b]$.
Here is my attempt:
Let $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ where $m \leq i$ be the simple roots of $p_i(x)$ on the interval $[a, b]$ and define the polynomial
$$q(x) = (x - x_1)(x - x_2) \cdots (x - x_m).$$
For the sake of contradiction, suppose that $p_i(x) = q(x) \cdot r(x)$ such that $q(x) \geq 0 \ \forall x \in [a, b]$. This implies that $r(x) = p_i(x)/q(x)$. Then, the product
$$r(x) \cdot p_i(x) = r(x) \cdot q(x) \cdot r(x) = (r(x))^2 q(x)$$
is non-negative on the interval $[a, b]$ since $q(x) \geq 0$ by assumption and $(r(x))^2 \geq 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, $r(x) \cdot p_i(x)$ is not identically 0 on $[a, b]$ for if it were, either $q(x)$ or $r(x)$ would be identically 0 on $[a, b]$ which neither are. Therefore, the inner product $\langle 1, r(x) \cdot p_i(x) \rangle > 0$. \\
By assumption, $p_i(x)$ is orthogonal to all polynomials of degree less than $i$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $\deg(q(x)) > 0$ which implies the degree of $r(x) = p_i(x) / q(x)$ is less than $i$. It follows that the inner product $\langle r(x), p_i(x) \rangle = 0$. However, this is a contradiction since we have deduced that
$$\langle 1, r(x) \cdot p_i(x) \rangle > 0 \iff \int_a^b 1 \cdot r(x) \cdot p_i(x) \ dx > 0$$
and
$$\langle r(x), p_i(x) \rangle = 0 \iff \int_a^b r(x) \cdot p_i(x) \ dx = 0.$$
Therefore, our supposition must be false and $p_i(x)$ must not have any factor $q(x) \geq 0$. In particular, $q(x) = (x - \alpha)^2$ cannot be a factor of $p_i(x)$ and hence $p_i(x)$ has $i$ distinct roots on $[a, b]$.
Questions:
I think maybe this proof is not complete since $m$ could potentially be less than $i$. How do I show that $p_i(x)$ has precisely $i$ distinct roots in the interval $[a, b]$?
Answer inspired by: why must orthogonal polynomials each have distinct roots?

What is $q(x)$? Is it meant to capture all of the roots in $[a, b]$? It seems yes to me, but then 1/ Why isn't $k = m$? (could be just a typo), 2/ How do we deal with non-simple roots, and 3/ Why would $q(x) \geq 0$ (which implies double roots)? $\quad$ Apart from the implications of the above, how do you assume that $deg(q(x)) > 0 $? IE How do you know that it has a root in $[a,b]$ (or whatever the definition is)?  $\quad$ Agree with you that you in no way showed that $m = k = i $, so your proof is almost certainly incorrect.

(1) Yes, $q(x)$ is meant to capture all the simple roots of $p_i(x)$ in $[a, b]$. I was thinking $m$ may be less than $k$ if $p_i$ has a non-simple roots (this addresses (2)). For (3), we are assuming this in order to obtain a contradiction (for the contrary is that $p_i$ does not have a factor with a non-simple root $\implies$ $p_i(x)$ cannot have a root of multiplicity $> 1$). I think the proof is almost there...

For (3), if $q(x)$ has degree $\geq 1$ and only has simple roots in the domain, then it cannot satisfy $ q(x) \geq 0$ in the domain. EG if $q(\alpha) = 0 $, then $q( \alpha ^-)$ and $ q(\alpha^+)$ have different signs.   $\quad$ On the other hand, you might be wanting that either $r(x) \geq $ or $-r(x) \geq 0$. However, that is still not true if in the case of $p(x)$ having triple roots (and so that root is not assigned to $q(x) $).

@CalvinLin Would you mind having a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368292/why-must-orthogonal-polynomials-each-have-distinct-roots and comparing it to my adapted proof to see where I went off the rails? I am quite confused.

For (2), you already said that $x_1$ to $x_m$ are all of the simple roots. And you want all of them to be in $q(x)$, so it has degree $m$. Thus $m = k$ (and so using $k$ just introduces confusion).

Hint: Do NOT let your notation do double duty, which easily leads to obvious issues. In particular, when person A defines something, in person B's answer they should make sure the notation does the same thing. $\quad$ Chris is guilty of making this mistake.

@CalvinLin I think you are hinting that $q(x)$ in the OP attempt has no relation to Chris' $q(t)$? Hence my proof unnecessarily defined $q(x)$ as being the simple zeros of $p_i(x)$?

Yup, hence my confusion about what $q(x)$ really is. Given that you weren't able to spot that issue, it indicates to me that you're not clear on what you're doing, and just blindly copying/adapting an existing solution. As such, I'd encourage you to  run through your proof and see how that affects things.  $\quad$ FWIW I believe you'd still end up with an issue, since the domain is not $ \mathbb{R}$.

Ok, thank you. I have spent a considerable amount of time on this problem and I think I finally understand it. I believe the argument works, with a few tweaks. BTW, restricting the domain to $[a, b]$ does not affect the argument since $p_i$ are assumed to be orthogonal on $[a, b]$.

We have to prove the following: $p_k$ has no complex roots, no real double (or higher) root and no root outside the interval when $k \ge 1$
Assume $p_k$ has a complex root hence it has its conjugate as a root so $p_k(x)=q(x)r(x)$ where $q$ is a positive quadratic and nonzero $r$ has degree $k-2$ (here $k \ge 2$ automatically). But then since $<p_k,r>=0$ we get $\int_a^bq(x)r^2(x)=0$ and that is a contradiction since $q>0, r$ not identically zero.
Assume $p_k$ has a real double root $\alpha$ and the proof above goes the same since now $q(x)=(x-\alpha)^2 >0, x \ne \alpha$ so if $p_k=qr, r$ not identically zero, we have that the integral $\int_a^bq(x)r^2(x)>0$ contradicting $<p_k,r>=0$.
Assume now $p_k(x)=(x-\alpha)r(x), \alpha \le a$ (or $\alpha \ge b$ which is similar)
Then again $<p_k, r>=0$ and now $x-\alpha >0$ for all $\alpha >a$ so again we get the contradiction $0=\int_a^b(x-\alpha)r^2(x)>0$.
This shows that all the roots of $p_k$ are simple and contained inside $(a,b)$
